# php file is downloaded when I run docker-compose, php7 and nginx together

Tags: php, docker, nginx

When I run the following docker-compose file, all services run fine, but when I open the following link, **browser downloads a hello-world.php** file instead of showing its content.

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/hello-world.php
```

Here's my file structure:

```
docker-compose.yml
site.conf
www     
   hello-world.php
```

Here's my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
      - php
  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
       - ./www:/usr/share/nginx/html/
```

This is my site.conf

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

And this is my hello world:

```
<?php
    echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: In the question, `php:` is at the same level as `links:`.  Is it in your actual `docker-compose.yml`, or is that a copy error?  It should be at the same level as `web:`, unindented by one step.  (You can just delete `links:` and simplify the file slightly.)

Comment: Yes it's in the same level. My typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a better nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```